# Component c:attachment does not exist in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am new to the salesforce and I have developed the below code but facing the error **Component c:attachment does not exist** why ?

```
<apex:page controller="sendEmail">
    <apex:messages/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Send an Email to Your {!account.name} Representatives">
        <p>Fill out the fields below to test how you might send an email to a user.</p>

        <apex:dataTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="contact" border="1">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                {!contact.Name}
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Email</apex:facet>
                {!contact.Email}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>

        <apex:form><br/><br/>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Subject" for="Subject"/>: <br/>     
            <apex:inputText value="{!subject}" id="Subject" maxlength="80"/>
            <br/><br/>

            <apex:outputLabel value="Body" for="Body"/>: <br/>     
            <apex:inputTextarea value="{!body}" id="Body" rows="10" cols="80"/>           
            <br/><br/>

            <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}"/> 
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock title="Preview the Attachment for {!account.name}">
        <c:attachment/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Nothing by that name appears in the Visualforce Standard Component Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref.htm

What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Hey I am following link from here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171985/how-to-send-case-attachment-in-email-for-approval-process. This is what I need to achieve.

Comment: Did you create a custom component named "attachment," as described in that article?

Comment: Nope. How we can create that ?

Comment: Go to the developer console, click File > New > Visualforce Component. Then name it "attachment." Then follow the rest of the steps in that article. Specifically, this section: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm#DefiningCustomComponentAttachment